# Create new variable based off multiple "OR" conditions within a pre-existing variable in R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I would like to insert a new variable into my data frame based off multiple conditions in a pre-existing variable I already have a variable in my dataset (dataset- Maj2014), "SiteID", which is a variable containing the site name (e.g. MA1, MA2...etc) and I wish to use this information to create a new variable "OuterOrLagoon" which is based off the site name and allocates the sites to be either "Lagoon" (i.e. a site inside a Lagoon) or "Outer" (i.e. a site on the outer reef).

Thus far I have created the new variable and filled it with NA's

```
Maj2014["OuterOrLagoon"] <- NA
```

and have created the following code in an attempt to use the "if else" function to solve the problem

```
Maj2014$OuterOrLagoon <- ifelse(Maj2014$SiteID == MA1|MA2|MA5|MA6|MA9|MA13, "Outer",
ifelse(Maj2014$SiteID == MA3|MA7|MA8|MA10|MA15, "Lagoon"))
```

However it returns the following error

```
Error in ifelse(Maj2014$SiteID == MA1 | MA2 | MA5 | MA6 | MA9 | MA13,  : 
object 'MA1' not found
```

So basically in my new variable "OuterOrLagoon" I want to call any rows with the SiteID of MA1, MA2, MA5, MA6, MA9 and MA13 - "Outer" and the rows with MA3, MA7, MA8, MA10 and MA15 - "Lagoon".

So the first question is, "is the method and code I am attempting to use to solve this problem correct?"
And the next is "if correct, how do I fix the error?"

I realise this is probably a relatively straightforward problem but if anyone can please help that would be great!

Thankyou,

Tyson

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
 Maj2014$OuterOrLagoon  <- with(Maj2014, ifelse(SiteID %in%
        c('MA1','MA2','MA5','MA6','MA9','MA13'), "Outer",
     ifelse(SiteID %in% c('MA3','MA7','MA8','MA10','MA15'), "Lagoon", NA)))  

 head(Maj2014)
 # SiteID        val OuterOrLagoon
 #1    MA5  0.4892584         Outer
 #2    MA4  0.2526488          <NA>
 #3   MA11 -1.6783948          <NA>
 #4    MA8 -0.7103328        Lagoon
 #5   MA10 -1.0449426        Lagoon
 #6   MA14 -0.7980727          <NA>
```

#### Update

Regarding the followup, you need `&` in place of `&&`.  According to the `?&`

> ```
>  ‘&’ and ‘&&’ indicate logical AND and ‘|’ and ‘||’ indicate
>  logical OR.  The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in
>  much the same way as arithmetic operators.  The longer form
>  evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each
>  vector.  Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined.
>  The longer form is appropriate for programming control-flow and
>  typically preferred in ‘if’ clauses.
> ```

This should work:

```
RM12014$Complexity <- with(RM12014, ifelse(SiteID == 'RT8' & Depth == 10, 5,
                                 ifelse(SiteID=='RT8' & Depth ==3, 5, NA)) )

head(RM12014)
# SiteID Depth Complexity
#1    RT7    10         NA
#2    RT7     3         NA
#3    RT7     3         NA
#4    RT8     3          5
#5    RT7     3         NA
#6    RT8     7         NA
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(24)
 Maj2014 <- data.frame(SiteID= sample(paste0('MA',1:15),25,
              replace=TRUE), val=rnorm(25))

 set.seed(28)
 RM12014 <- data.frame(SiteID= sample(paste0('RT', 7:8), 25, 
            replace=TRUE), Depth= sample(c(3,10,7), 25, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: Thankyou, the first section of code works nicely and allocates the sites to either the "Lagoon" or "Outer". However, how do I then allocate this information into the "OuterOrLagoon" variable? It doesn't come up as being inserted into the variable space when I view the dataset?

Comment: @TysonMartin If you notice the code and data, I didn't create an variable `OuterOrLagoon` as `NA`, but even if that is the case, the code should work.

Comment: thank you very much, I just allocated it to the variable and it worked! Thankyou!

Comment: could u plz hlp with follow up qn. Now trying to apply ur suggestion to the same data but this time with 2 conditions to be met and a no. to be allocated to rows of a new var which fits both of the conditions.   RMI2014$Complexity <- ifelse(RMI2014$SiteID %in% c('RT8') && RMI2014$Depth %in% c('10'), "5",ifelse(RMI2014$SiteID %in% c('RT8') && RMI2014$Depth %in% c('3'), "5", NA)) e.g. if SiteID has a value of RT8 and a 10 in the Depth column give a value of 5 in the new complexity column (obviously repeated for all sites). But it only returns a value of 1 every time. How do I fix? thnxs

Answer (score 0):

You can do it more efficiently without `ifelse`:

```
transform(Maj2014, 
          OuterOrLagoon = c("Lagoon", NA, "Outer")
          [(tmp <- as.integer(sub("\\D+", "", SiteID))) %in% c(1, 2, 5, 9, 13) -
             tmp %in% c(3, 7, 8, 10, 15) + 2])
```